# update data of D3.js treemap

Tags: d3.js

as the title says, I'm struggling to update the data on my treemap.
I've already created several other charts of different complexity.

To be more specific: 
My data constists of use cases with multiple test cases & dates.
I got a range slider for the date range, if changed, the chart should update.
It basically shows if all test cases of a use case in specific time range have passed:

```
createCells () {
  this.cell = this.group.selectAll('g')
    .data(this.root.children)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', d => `node ${d.children ? 'node--internal' : 'node--leaf'}`)
    .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x0}, ${d.y0})`)

  this.cell.append('rect')
    .attr('id', d => d.data.id)
    .attr('width', d => d.x1 - d.x0)
    .attr('height', d => d.y1 - d.y0)
    .attr('fill', d => this.color(this.checkTests(d.data.values)))
}


update () {
  this.treemap(this.root)

  let rects = this.group.selectAll('rect')
    .data(this.root.children)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', d => `node ${d.children ? 'node--internal' : 'node--leaf'}`)
    .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x0}, ${d.y0})`)

  rect.append('rect')
    .attr('id', d => d.data.id)
    .attr('width', d => d.x1 - d.x0)
    .attr('height', d => d.y1 - d.y0)
    .attr('fill', d => this.color(this.checkTests(d.data.values)))
    .on('mouseover', this.tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', this.tip.hide)
    .on('click', d => this.showDetails(d))
    .merge(temp)
    .attr('fill', d => this.color(this.checkTests(d.data.values)))

  rect.exit().remove()
}
```

The problem now is, that with the filtered data the treemap repositions its elements. Though normally this would be desired behaviour, this should not happen as I am only interested in potential color changes (red/green). I think this is due to the hirarchical structure of the treemap layout.

Thank you in advance!

::edited::

Comment: if you don't wat the rects to move on update why do you change transform,`width` and `height` of the rect? then the problem is in your `checkTests` function. Maybe select the `rect` first before the transition

Comment: I aldready tried it withouth the changing `width` and `height` without a result. Selecting `rects` before `transition` does not help either. I think this happens because of some change in the hierarchical structure. So the `rects` don't change, but the internal hierarchy does. At least it looks to me like that.

Comment: why recalc the tree if you only want color change based on some external selection logic

Comment: What does this have to do with Vue?

Comment: @RoyJ I use D3.js in combination with Vue.js -- so there are more options handling updates than with vanilla JS and D3.

Comment: @rioV8 Any suggestions for an update pattern? I couldn't come up with a better one so far :/

Comment: why don't you update the question with your answer? have a close read of `d3.selectAll()` docs and use the DOMTools to see what your error is.

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for the hint. I read more into it & updated my code -- it adds the new rects, but keeps the old ones completely so that the new SVGs lie beneath the old ones :/

Comment: [The comment of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848237/d3-treemap-dynamic-data-not-adjusting-cell-width-height) @Mark helped me to get closer to the solution. Still not completely working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution is the following.

```
    update () {
      let rect = this.group.selectAll('g')
        .data(this.root.children)

      // EXIT and REMOVE
      rect.exit().remove()

      // ENTER
      let nRect = rect.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x0}, ${d.y0})`)
        .attr('class', d => `node ${d.children ? 'node--internal' : 'node--leaf'}`)

      nRect.append('rect')
        .attr('id', d => d.data.id)
        .attr('width', d => d.x1 - d.x0)
        .attr('height', d => d.y1 - d.y0)
        .attr('fill', d => this.color(this.checkTests(d.data.values)))
        .on('mouseover', this.tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', this.tip.hide)
        .on('click', d => this.showDetails(d))
        .merge(rect)
        .attr('fill', d => this.color(this.checkTests(d.data.values)))

      // UPDATE
      rect.attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x0}, ${d.y0})`)

      rect.select('rect')
        .attr('width', d => d.x1 - d.x0)
        .attr('height', d => d.y1 - d.y0)
        .attr('fill', d => this.color(this.checkTests(d.data.values)))
        .on('mouseover', this.tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', this.tip.hide)
        .on('click', d => this.showDetails(d))
        .merge(rect)
        .attr('fill', d => this.color(this.checkTests(d.data.values)))
    }
```

What I did wrong was not applying the exit/remove/enter/update correctly. Maybe this could have bee achieved by using the merge functionality aswell?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848237/d3-treemap-dynamic-data-not-adjusting-cell-width-height) helped me, figuring out what was going wrong :)